# Matlab's writetable() function only exporting partial data of a table

Tags: matlab, export-to-excel

The *writetable()* function at the end of my code only exports the first row (namely FR_1w, FR_2w and FR_3w), whereas I want the **entire table to be exported and written as .xls or .xlsx**.

```
V=[{A B C};...
    {A1 B1 C1};...
    {A2 B2 C2}];
X=cell2table(V);
X.Properties.VariableNames= {'FR_1w' 'FR_2w' 'FR_3w'};
X.Properties.RowNames= {'4Weeks' '12Weeks' '24Weeks'};
writetable(X, 'X.xlsx')
```

n.b. Variables in table V are *3x1 cells*.
A, for example, contains:

[image]

Comment: Works for me, if I use `V=[{1 2 3}; {4 5 6}; {7 8 9}];` Which version of Matlab and Excel are you using?

Comment: yes it works if you put in numbers, but my variables are 3x1 cells, e.g. "A" contains 3 different values.
Matlab version 2016b and Excel (Mac) 2011

Comment: Then update the question with concrete data that matches your data, otherwise I'm just guessing.

Comment: see above for a detailed look at my variables

Comment: Please write the values of the variable in the code example, so I can just copy-paste.

Comment: Another question, what do you expect to be written to the excel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround solution:

```
Z=[{A{1,1} B{1,1} C{1,1}};...
   {A{2,1} B{2,1} C{2,1}};...
   {A{3,1} B{3,1} C{3,1}};...
   {A1{1,1} B1{1,1} C1{1,1}};...
   {A1{2,1} B1{2,1} C1{2,1}};...
   {A1{3,1} B1{3,1} C1{3,1}};...
   {A2{1,1} B2{1,1} C2{1,1}};...
   {A2{2,1} B2{2,1} C2{2,1}};...
   {A2{3,1} B2{3,1} C2{3,1}}];

Tstat = cell2table(VV);
Tstat.Properties.VariableNames = {'ok1' 'ok2' 'ok3'};
Tstat.Properties.RowNames = {'one' 'two' 'three' 'four' 'five' ...
'six' 'seven' 'eight' 'nine'};
writetable(Tstat, 'TstatOverview.xlsx')
```